# How can I install Subversion 1.7?

Tags: 10.04, server, package-management, svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subversion 1.7 Binary](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65468/subversion-1-7-binary)

For various reasons I need a newer version of Subversion (SVN) running on my 10.04 server, how can I install subversion without having to compile it from source (I really only need the client and building APR and all of the rest of the requirements seems potentially problematic when there must be a package for it somewhere that will run on Ubuntu 10.04).  I just don't know where to search for packages and googling subversion 1.7 hasn't helped at all.