# Will ubuntu support subversion1.7 and when will it be?

Tags: svn

Since svn is the most widely used centralized source collaboration repository: are there plans for supporting the current version (1.7) out of the box in the near future?

Comment: For the current 12.04 LTS you can get it installed following the answers in http://askubuntu.com/questions/65468/where-can-i-find-a-subversion-1-7-binary. There's one mentioning the "Subversion team" PPA, which, IMHO, is your best bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ rmadison -u ubuntu -s quantal subversion
subversion | 1.7.5-1ubuntu2 |       quantal | source, amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
```

Looks like 12.10 has version 1.7.5 of Subversion in the repository already.

---

Now, if you are asking whether 12.04 and the older versions would have the latest version, I would say no.

See also:

- [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)
- [Why can't I update applications without upgrading the whole OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95336/why-cant-i-update-applications-without-upgrading-the-whole-os/95586#95586)
- [Where can I find a Subversion 1.7 binary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65468/where-can-i-find-a-subversion-1-7-binary)

Comment: I can verify on http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/subversion.