# Where can I find a Subversion 1.8 binary?

Tags: software-installation, svn

The Subversion 1.8 was released two weeks ago and is already available on the Windows platform via the Tortoise SVN client.

I would like to get it running on my Ubuntu 12.04 box.

I've already checked the [Subversion team](https://launchpad.net/~svn/+archive/ppa) ppa, however, the latest to be found is 1.7.9.

Does anybody know of a ppa or source that I can use in order to get it running?

Comment: I've just upgraded to NetBeans 8, which uses 1.8 internally, and tries to force an upgrade on 1.7 trees. At the time of writing, the 1.8 console client still isn't available in the default Ubuntu repo (13.10) so I suspect I'll compile my own from source. I'm pleased there's external repos available, but I'm cautious about adding repo references that I've not heard of.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As [described in this previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/71085/190923) (thanks [Fernando](https://askubuntu.com/users/27609/fernando)!), the "installer" shell script which [WANDisco](http://www.wandisco.com/) provide is actually just installing a standard APT repository. Although they ask for your details before you can download the script, there seem to be no terms and conditions attached to using their repository without doing so.

The below should add the repository on 12.04 Precise (the repository doesn't contain a `Source` directory, which the `add-apt-repository` command assumes it will, so I have used a slightly different method).

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "# WANdisco Open Source Repo" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/WANdisco.list'
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://opensource.wandisco.com/ubuntu precise svn18" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/WANdisco.list'
wget -q http://opensource.wandisco.com/wandisco-debian.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

To confirm that the new subversion package has been detected, run:

```
apt-cache show subversion | grep '^Version:'
```

If the 1.8 package is listed, you should then be able to install as normal:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

Comment: Works with 13.10 too.

Answer (score 8):

It seems WANdisco has 1.8 available for Ubuntu 12.04 Precise.

http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#ubuntu_precise

Comment: I haven't checked, but it looks like [this post about subversion 1.7](http://askubuntu.com/a/71085/190923) can be trivially adapted to use this like a PPA rather than downloading their install script. Based on [the directory structure](http://opensource.wandisco.com/ubuntu/dists/) the first line would be `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://opensource.wandisco.com/ubuntu precise svn18'`

Comment: Confirmed and expanded into a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Command Line Client 1.8 is hosted at Assembla, no need to give your email
http://svn-ref.assembla.com/download-clients.html#Ubuntu

Comment: The download on that link is just (a modified version of?) the WanDisco install script. The binaries themselves are being installed from the WanDisco repository.

Answer (score 2):

There is an experimental ppa on launchpad:

https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/subversion-1.8