# How do I download and install libraries from url

Tags: 12.04

I want to install `subversion 1.7` using its .deb file. Subversion needs `libsvn1` which in turn requires many other files. I found a link to download `libsvn` and its dependencies at http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libsvn1

How do I make Ubuntu download `libsvn1` along with all these dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

**Select Software Repositories**

`sudo software-properties-gtk`

[image]

[image]

**Update repositories**

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`

**Download `subversion`**

`mkdir subversion; cd subversion; wget -c --read-timeout=3 -t 0 $(apt-get install --reinstall --print-uris -qq subversion | cut -d"'" -f2)`

**Install `subversion`**

`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

**If any version problem arises try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65468/where-can-i-find-a-subversion-1-7-binary)**